# Spark Scala - textFile() and sequenceFile() RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm successfully loading my sequence files into a DataFrame with some code like this:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sc.sequenceFile[LongWritable,String](src)
val jsonRecs = file.map((record: (String, String)) => new String(record._2))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(jsonRecs)
```

I'd like to do the same with some text files.  The text files have a similar format as the sequence files (A timestamp, a tab char, then the json).  But the problem is textFile() returns an RDD[String] instead of an RDD[LongWritable,String] like the sequenceFile() method.

My goal is to be able to test the program with either sequence files or text files as input.

How could I convert the RDD[String] coming from textFile() into an RDD[LongWritable,String]?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Your text file is a CSV file?

Comment: `sc.textFile("text file").map(_.split("\t"))` ?

Comment: That was part of the puzzle, but it doesn't return the right type I need.  I needed a way to tranform the return value of textFile() to be exactly the same type as what's returned from sequenceFile().

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your text file is a CSV file, you can use following code for reading a CSV file in a Dataframe where `spark` is the SparkSession:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("file.txt")
```

Like header option there are multiple options you can provide depending upon your requirement. Check [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses.  It's not a CSV but I guess it could be.  It's just the text output of doing this on a sequence file in HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/my/file > myFile.txt
```

Anyway, I found a solution that works for both sequence and text file for my use case.  This code ends up setting the variable 'file' to a RDD[String,String] in both cases, and I can work with that.

```
var file = if (inputType.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
      sc.textFile(src).map(line => (line.split("\t")(0), line.split("\t")(1)))
} else { // Default to assuming sequence files are input
      sc.sequenceFile[String,String](src)
}
```